# npm run asbuild ERR

Tags: typescript, assemblyscript

how to fix the bug of asbuild

[image]

> ```
> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:149:18)
> ```

```bash
npm install --save-dev assemblyscript
npx asinit .
Y
npm run asbuild
```

here is the .log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\NoIdea_C\\AppData\\Local\\nvs\\default\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\NoIdea_C\\AppData\\Local\\nvs\\default\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'asbuild'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.18
3 info using node@v14.21.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'preasbuild', 'asbuild', 'postasbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preasbuild: @
6 info lifecycle @~asbuild: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~asbuild: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~asbuild: PATH: C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\nvs\node\14.21.3\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\Desktop\AssemblyScript\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;D:\Bandizip\Bandizip;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe;D:\微信web开发者工具\dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\ZeroTier\One\;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\scoop\shims;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\nvs\default;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\nvs\;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\.npm_global;D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;c:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\Programs\Cursor\resources\app\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin;D:\platform-tools;F:\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl-shared\bin;C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\android-ndk-r18b;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;
9 verbose lifecycle @~asbuild: CWD: C:\Users\NoIdea_C\Desktop\AssemblyScript
10 silly lifecycle @~asbuild: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run asbuild:debug && npm run asbuild:release' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~asbuild: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~asbuild: Failed to exec asbuild script
13 verbose stack Error: @ asbuild: `npm run asbuild:debug && npm run asbuild:release`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\nvs\node\14.21.3\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NoIdea_C\AppData\Local\nvs\node\14.21.3\x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\NoIdea_C\Desktop\AssemblyScript
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
17 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\NoIdea_C\\AppData\\Local\\nvs\\default\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\NoIdea_C\\AppData\\Local\\nvs\\default\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "asbuild"
18 verbose node v14.21.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.18
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ asbuild: `npm run asbuild:debug && npm run asbuild:release`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ asbuild script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I as know, `asbuild` is unmaintained and may not work with the current `assemblyscript`. The last [commit](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/asbuild) is from May 2021.

You can build your code with by running `npm run asbuild`, which is a `npm` script that `asinit` puts in your `package.json`, you should already have it. That's it! [Documentation link](https://www.assemblyscript.org/getting-started.html#setting-up-a-new-project) for good measure.